# How do I use fetchAll in php?

Tags: php, sql, fetchall

I am using this statement to fetch the elements in a column in my db

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

but I get this error when trying to run it.

Call to undefined method `mysqli_stmt::fetchAll();`

Is there something I need to add to my php file to include that method or something?

UPDATE 1:

```
class LoginAPI
{
private $db;

function __construct() 
{
    $this->db = new mysqli('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
    $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
}

function __destruct() 
{
    $this->db->close();
}

function login() 
{
    if(isset($_POST["lang"]))
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT code FROM locations");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($code);

        //while($stmt->fetch())
        //{
        //  result[] = "code"=>$code;
        //  break;
        //}
        $codeArr = array();
        $result = $stmt->fetch_all();//|PDO::FETCH_GROUP;




        sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
        return true;
    }
    sendResponse(400, 'Invalid Request');
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like your mixing PDO and mysqli. If you post how you connect it will show you're making a mysqli connection object, not PDO statement. A mysqli result set object have fetch_all() and not a function fetchAll(). fetchAll() is a function provided by PDOStatement class. See this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: you are using `PDO` or `mysqli`? In any case, you are mixing the two here.

Comment: Please check http://us1.php.net/pdostatement.fetchall#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-examples

Comment: Here is how I am connecting to the DB $this->db = new mysqli(...);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using mysqli, and you've got a statement not a result.  If you have a mysqli_result you could be using the method `fetch_all()`.

However, as this is a mysqli_stmt, you first need to execute and then use `fetch_all()` on the result set.  See below example

```
 $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT code FROM locations");
 $stmt->execute();


//grab a result set
$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();

//pull all results as an associative array
$result = $resultSet->fetch_all();
```

Note: with fetch_all you don't need to bind the result as your original code.

Comment: I changed it to fetch_all() and now I get there error for that method. I am still quite new to all of this, so sorry if I am being stupid

Comment: @linuxer Also are you using php 5.3 or an earlier version

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all() and my PHP version is 5.3.15

Comment: @linuxer Ok, now that I look at this I see a lot more going on.  Can you put how you create a connection and create your sql statement?  It looks like you're using a prepared statement.  If so do you call execute?   Just paste in your example the whole block of mysqli commands you use